# Sparx Enterprise Architect: SysML IBD - How to display nested sub-blocks as boxes (rectangles)?

Tags: enterprise-architect, sysml

I have an IBD defining the content of block, which includes nested blocks, where:

Block A - shown as a box (rectangle)

Block A contains:

- Block A1 shown as a box (rectangle)

And Block A1 contains

- Block X
- Block Y
- Block Z
  where all three of Block X, Block Y, and Block Z are displayed as just text under the *parts* heading

Question: How can I make EA display Block X, Block Y, and Block Z as boxes (rectangles)?

Comment: An example (image) would help.

Comment: You should probably cross-post on Sparx' forum. There are some SysML users. Here it's rather Geert and me.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the IBD select :Block A1.
2. In the Parts/Properties tab in the Features window (right click->Features->Parts/Properties) you should see Block X, Block Y, Block Z. Note there is a column for Visible in which all entries should be False.
3. To show Block X, Y and Z as nested rectangles on the IBD just click on the checkbox for each row.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to:
improve text arragement, improve code formatting

See [answer]

Comment: @Gander, now it passes muster? The answer it did not include code.